# Как подключить mini usb host shield к ардуино

Tags: arduino

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня есть arduino pro mini 5V и мини юсб хост шилд.
Не могу разобраться как их соединить.
Допустим 5v я соединяю с vcc на плате,
землю с землей...
а как подсоединить d+ d- ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D+ и D- не нужно подключать. С Arduino эта плата работает по интерфейсу SPI через ICSP-коннектор.

В целом подключение идентично USB Host Shield, подробно описанному [здесь](https://chome.nerpa.tech/usb-host-shield-hardware-manual/).